# Can you identify this twin engine propeller aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-identification

[image: Twin-engine passenger aircraft]

On the ramp at Orange County Airport New York.

Comment: My spidey senses are saying Saab 340 or 2000?

Answer (score 11):

It is a Freight Runners Express Saab 2000.

Freight Runners Express is a US air carrier based in Milwaukee, Wisconsin, United States. The airline operates scheduled and on-demand air cargo and passenger services. Passenger air charter services are also operated under the Air Charter Express (ACE) brand using Embraer EMB-120 and Saab 2000 aircraft.[1](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Freight-Runners-Express/Saab-2000/6968929) Freight Runners is headquartered at Milwaukee Mitchell International Airport in Milwaukee.

[Airliners.net Photo](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Freight-Runners-Express/Saab-2000/6968929)
[image]